# "Про Россию" или "о России"?

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, согласование, предлоги

Правильно ли говорить: "Я думаю про Россию" или "я думаю о России".

Answer (score 1):

В целом эти два предлога выступают синонимами, когда употребляются при обозначении объекта разговора, размышлений и т.п., ср.: *Расскажи мне про своего нового друга / о своём новом друге.* Однако **полными** синонимами их назвать всё же нельзя; в частности, предлог *про* зачастую указывает на более конкретное действие, а предлог *о* – на более отвлечённое. С глаголом *думать,* пожалуй, лучше сочетается предлог *о*: *думаю о России.* С глаголом *писать*, обозначающим более конкретно-практическое действие, – оба: *пишу про Россию / о России.*  Но это, конечно, рекомендации, а не жёсткие правила.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, "про" чаще встречается в украинском языке (точнее, это там единственно возможный предлог), а в русском - все-таки "о".

Comment: Слова «в русском – всё-таки *о*» означают, что в русской речи он употребляется чаще, чем *про*, или что-то более категоричное?

Answer (score 0):

"Про" - разговорный вариант. Корректнее употреблять "о".